# How can I set a different action on different select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, action

I want to have a different action linked to different option value when I click the apply button and here is my code:

```
<select class="input-sm form-control" id="pendingbulk">
   <option value="0">Bulk Actions</option>
   <option value="1">Accept</option>
   <option value="2">Reject</option>
   <option value="3">Report</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="pendingapply">Apply</button>

<script>
   $("#pendingapply").onclick(function() {
   var action = $('#pendingbulk').val();
   if (action == 1) {
     $(this).attr("action", "/accept/" + action);
   } else if (action == 2) {
     $(this).attr("action", "/reject/" + action);
   } else if (action == 3) {
     $(this).attr("action", "/report/" + action);
   };
   })
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `form` has `action` attribute not button.

Comment: $(this) should be pointing to a form instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form` has `action` attribute not button. If your button is wrapped in a form you should use

```
$(this).closest('form').attr("action", ActionString);
```

OR, simply add an ID to you form and use

```
$('#YourFormId').attr("action", ActionString);
```

Also use, `.click()`

```
$("#pendingapply").click(function() { //Typo here
```

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the attribute to the wrong element

```
$(this).attr("action", "/accept/" + action);
```

will apply the action attribute to the button and not your form.

You need to target your form:

```
$("#myFormId").attr("action", "/accept/" + action);
```

Also you are using the wrong method for the jquery object, its `.click` not `.onclick`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function f(){
var pendingbulk = document.getElementById("pendingbulk");
var myArrays = new Array();
myArrays[0] = pendingbulk.options[0]
myArrays[1] = pendingbulk.options[1]
myArrays[2] = pendingbulk.options[2]
myArrays[3] = pendingbulk.options[3]

for (var i=0 ; i< myArrays.length ; i++){
if (myArrays[i].selected){
location.href = myArrays[i].value
}
}
}
</script>
<select class="input-sm form-control" id="pendingbulk">
   <option value="0">Bulk Actions</option>
   <option value="1">Accept</option>
   <option value="2">Reject</option>
   <option value="3">Report</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="pendingapply" onclick='f()'>Apply</button>
```

Comment: You should post an explanation along with your code.

Comment: It will be good to provide some explanation, not only the code.